# How to convert current date time to Math.PI?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

Is there any direct function/method availability in ECMA or vanilla to convert current time to Math.PI multiplier but in the series of max Math.PI and min 0? The time difference between two results can be any second(s).

Comment: Are you talking about angle in radians?

Comment: Yes, I am talking about radians.

Comment: Then, which language, only one question per post is allowed, also, what have you tried, though the answer to the actual question is no, there is not any native function for this.

Comment: OK, then can you please provide the logic as I just require the logic for the same. I can convert them into the other. But I will prefer javascript

Comment: Just for clarity, you know radian values within a single round are from 0 to 2PI ..? You'd want to reflect any amount of seconds to from 0 to PI only?

Comment: Yes, you got me right!

Comment: That's prettey simple math, isn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this something that you might want?

```
var currDateTime = new Date();
var asString = "" + currDateTime.getHours() + currDateTime.getMinutes() + currDateTime.getSeconds() + currDateTime.getMilliseconds();
var inRadians = Math.sin(asString);
alert(inRadians);
```

Pure vanilla solution. You can omit milliseconds if you want, use cos etc..

Comment: Thanks, @dantethesmith this is the answer I was seeking. Can you also explain the solution too.